# Perl script redirect stderr and stdout to a file

Tags: perl, unix, stdout, csh

I'm having trouble doing this. My script prints messages to stout and stderr, and I want them all to be directed to a file that I can view at my leisure later.

Here is what I tried:

```
$location/myscript.pl -arg1 $var1 -arg2 $var2 -verbose 1 &>myscript.log
```

So my script has a few arguments that I need to set, then I try **&>myscript.log** to create this log file and redirect there. However I get "Invalid null command" and when I press up on the key pad it shows the command I tried executing as:

```
$location/myscript.pl -arg1 $var1 -arg2 $var2 -verbose 1 & > myscript.log
```

I think my syntax is wrong or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
script.pl ... >myscript.log 2>&1
```

- `>myscript.log` opens the file for writing and uses that handle for STDOUT.
- `2>&1` makes STDERR the same handle as STDOUT.

Order matters.

---

For `csh`, the simplest way is:

```
sh -c 'script.pl ... >myscript.log 2>&1'
```

Ok, I'm just kidding :) You can actually do

```
script.pl ... >& file
```

`csh`'s redirection support is far more limited than that of `sh` and its derivatives, but this is something it can do.

Comment: I still get "Invalid null command", literally copying and pasting the "myscript.log 2&>1" after my last argument ("-verbose 1"). I press up on the keypad, it separates the ">" and "&" characters by spaces, I have no clue why.. Something wrong with my environment?

Comment: Typo! fixed. (I had it right in the comment, but mistyped it in the actual command.)

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm getting "Ambiguous output redirect" now, I have a feeling it's about that -verbose 1 at the end, like it's taking 1 > myscript.log 2>&1

Comment: My research says that's a `csh`/`tcsh` error, but you asked for a `bash` solution. What shell are you using?

Comment: Shoot, come to think of it here at work they all use csh. Shouldn't have put bash. Know the fix by any chance? =)

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` should do the trick if it is installed somewhere :)

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge and research, looks like it's working now

Comment: All this and I dont see the direct answer.. in csh you direct stderr and stdout to the same file simply as   "command >& file".  What you can not readily do with csh is independently direct the streams.

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't follow your approach, but it could be useful for you as well. You could enable it via one of your agruments inside your script.

```
#===
# x.pl
#===
use IO::Handle;
open(STDOUT_AND_ERR_LOG, ">stdout_and_err.log") or die;

# ensure all writes are immediately flushed STDOUT_AND_ERR_LOG->autoflush(1);

# redirect both stdout and err to the log *STDERR = *STDOUT = *STDOUT_AND_ERR_LOG;

# now try it
print "Hello stdout!\n";
print STDERR "Hello stderr!\n";
#=== EOF
```

Credits to ActiveState.com

Comment: doesn't work under linux: Name "main::STDOUT_AND_ERR_LOG" used only once: possible typo at ....

Comment: You actually have to write the command mentioned in the 2nd comment. Please add `*STDERR = *STDOUT = *STDOUT_AND_ERR_LOG;` to your script to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by **ikegami**,  **bash** solution is:

```
script.pl ... >myscript.log 2>&1
```

On my FreeBSD box with **csh** solution is:

```
script.pl ... >& myscript.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$location/myscript.pl -arg1 $var1 -arg2 $var2 -verbose 1 1>myscript.stdout 2>myscript.stderr`

This will redirect the output and error to two separate files.  To do it in the same file (this means redirect stderr and append it to stdout):

`$location/myscript.pl -arg1 $var1 -arg2 $var2 -verbose 1 > myscript.log 2>&1`

Comment: Hang on just to clarify, "1" is the argument to the -verbose option (to turn it on)

Comment: I get "ambiguous output redirect" when adding "> myscript.log 2>&1" to then end of my call

Comment: try it with surrounding parentheses, ( ... ) ?

Comment: what about if you put 1 in quotes, e.g.  `-verbose "1" > myscript.log 2>&1`